# Cannot execute command in Freewitch event socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, sip, freeswitch

I need to send INFO SIP message to users. When I have some call I know it's channel Unique-ID. From fs_cli I can execute command

```
uuid_send_info <UUID> <my message>
```

And it works!
But if I try to send this command from Java Client object like

```
client.sendAsyncApiCommand("uuid_send_info", "<UUID> <my message>");
```

I receive from FreeSwitch response [+OK Success], but message not sending to user.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you turn up the log level on the fs_cli while you run `client.sendAsyncApiCommand("uuid_send_info", "<UUID> <my message>");` and see what it shows?

Comment: In debug mode if fs_cli I have only two records:
2017-10-13 02:05:29.545316 [DEBUG] switch_ivr.c:623 sofia/internal/<myuser>@<mydomain> Command Execute send_info(testmessage)
EXECUTE sofia/internal/<myuser>@<mydomain> send_info(testmessage)